# My code is not showing back the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code below:

```
$("#options").popup(null, Settings.DialogOptions)
.on("onOk", function(){
    Settings.SaveSettings( );
    Settings.CloseSettings( );

    switch(Settings.GetSetting("displayId")){
        case "true":
            $("#nextId").show();
            $("label[for=nextId]").show();
        break;

        case "false":
            $("#nextId").hide();
            $("label[for=nextId]").hide();
        break;
    }
});
```

I have to cases for testing my code:

1. `displayId = false` : **the code works properly**, it hides my two elements
2. `displayId = true` : **the code doesn't work**, my elemnents aren't shown back.

I don't get any error in console, but I don't know what to do to make my code work.Who can help me?

Comment: Can you show some more code. Perhaps some HTML and your Settings class?

Comment: is that a typo? true is supposed to show them, false is supposed to hide them, according to your code.

Comment: I have not a single idea of what you want to do. Explination please?

Comment: *"`displayId = true` : **the code works** properly, it hides my two elements"* That's not what the code *seems* to want to do when it's `true`. I see it showing, not hiding, elements for `"true"`.

Comment: There is some confusion by getting displayId 'true' you are showing two elements.

Comment: Try True (capital T) and False

Comment: excuse me, I have made a mistake in writing my question, my code is as it should

Comment: "true" and "false" should be `true` and `false`, not as strings

Comment: @dcodesmith: No, Victor says that `GetSetting` actually does return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really dealing with a string, it could be an issue of whitespace, or capitalization:

```
// ----v                                 -----v
switch($.trim(Settings.GetSetting("displayId")).toLowerCase() === "true"){
    case true:                             // <== No quotes
        $("#nextId").show();
        $("label[for=nextId]").show();
    break;

    case false:                            // <== No quotes
        $("#nextId").hide();
        $("label[for=nextId]").hide();
    break;
}
```

Of course, if you're dealing with true or false, `if/else` is the standard construct:

```
if ($.trim(Settings.GetSetting("displayId")).toLowerCase() === "true"){
    $("#nextId").show();
    $("label[for=nextId]").show();
}
else {
    $("#nextId").hide();
    $("label[for=nextId]").hide();
}
```

Or as you're just showing/hiding based on a flag:

```
$("#nextId").add("label[for=nextId]").toggle($.trim(Settings.GetSetting("displayId")).toLowerCase() === "true");
```

Comment: nope, actually, my setting is saved in `localStorage` and it is saved, of course, as a string. but, my second `case:` in the `switch` works. why the first one doesn't?

Comment: what does this help me with? `$.trim(Settings.GetSetting("displayId").toLowerCase())`

Comment: @Victor: `$.trim` removes whitespace. `toLowerCase` makes sure the string is in lower case. That way, `" True"`, `"True   "`, `" TRUE "`, and such all end up matching `"true"`. The branch is fine, so it has to be the value being tested.

Comment: Your idea is very good, but my `displayId` takes the value of `$("#checkBox").is(":checked");`

Comment: @Victor: Don't know what to tell you other than use the debugger built into your browser to single-step through and see what's happening. There's nothing wrong with the branching logic, it **has** to be the value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34465/discussion-between-victor-and-t-j-crowder)

Comment: @Victor: I see you've accepted this answer. Did it really solve the problem?